# Can't restore database: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

This is not a good day for me. I have a backup (master.bak) for SQL Server 2005 Express SP4 (v.9.0.500) that I want to restore to my master db instance. I am running SQL Server in single-user mode `(sqlservr.exe -m)`, connect to the instance, then I do a Task... Restore. This is the error I get:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express
>
> Restore failed for Server 'GINO\SQLEXPRESS'. 
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.2047.00&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Restore+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.SmoEnum)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
>   server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has
>   been ended.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 109)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=109&LinkId=20476

Please help me restore my backup database so that I can continue along with my business!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use SQLCMD instead of Management studio to do the restore and try this.  (Since you are using a named instance make sure to use the -S switch for SQLCMD)

```
C:\> SQLCMD -S GINO\SQLEXPRESS
> RESTORE DATABASE master FROM DISK='C:\SQLBackups\master.bak' WITH REPLACE;
> GO
```

Obviously replacing the path to your backup with the real path of where your backup is.

Have a look [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190679%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) for (slightly) more information.

Comment: I have tried your solution with an instance of SQLEXPRESS running in single-user mode:

Comment: Got it! I had to restart the server with `sqlcmd -m -S myserver`

Comment: Great!  Yeah, I was just getting in to make sure you were starting the server properly :)  That command doesn't start SQL Server, though.  It's just a command-line client to issue commands to SQL Server.